# How do you exclude object property in GWT from serialization?

Tags: java, gwt, serialization, properties

Is there a way to exclude primitive and Object properties within Serializable Object from GWT Serialization?

```
public class Provider implements Serializable{  
    public Provider() {  
    }  

    //Id like to exclude this property:   
        private String password;  
    //  

    private String address1;  
    private String address2;  
    private String companyName;  
    private String phone;  
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I was hoping for something like
>   special annotation

I think what you are looking for is `@GwtTransient`

> `@GwtTransient`, an annotation that
>   tells GWT RPC to treat a field as if
>   it were marked with the Java transient
>   keyword, even though it's not.
>
> This annotation means the same thing
>   as the `transient` keyword,
>   but it is ignored by all serialization
>   systems other than GWT's. Usually the
>   `transient` keyword should be used in
>   preference to this  annotation.
>   However, for types used with multiple
>   serialization systems, it can be
>   useful.

Reference: [@GwtTransient](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/GwtTransient.html)

Answer (score 7):

Can't you just declare it transient?

```
transient private String password;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to avoid using the *transient* keyword, you might want to look into **Custom Field Serializers**.

On my last GWT project, I used them to serialize immutable classes, since GWT-RPC had limitations for those.

It's a poorly documented feature, and the best explanation I found at the time was not in the GWT documentation, but on [this great wogwt wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/wogwt/wiki/CustomFieldSerializer). You may also find some examples in GWT's [com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/#svn/tags/2.1.0/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/core) package, since GWT uses a lot of those.

Please note that CustomFieldSerializers still have some issues, such as [issue 2931](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=2931) and [issue 3315](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3315). Also, I don't like the way they are defined: instead of using static methods, it would have been better to let users implement a `CustomFieldSerializer<T>` interface. We would have gained type safety and inheritance. But this is a whole other debate, and the GWT compiler might actually mandate the use of those static methods for performance reasons (I haven't looked into it).

Still, it works, and it's good to have them in specific cases.

Answer (score 0):

add transient to the field